# RSpec testing: post multiple params to methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am using RSpec to test my Rails 4 application and I want to post a "multiple select" param. The params method is like this:

```
  def general_mailing_params
    params.require(:mailing).permit({:receivers => []}, :subject, :content)
  end
```

As you can see the `receivers` param is a multiple select, how can I post this sort of params in RSpec test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RSpec controller and request specs you can simply pass arrays and hashes to create any given params hash.

Controller (functional) spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe MailingsController do

  let!(:receiver) { create(:receiver) }

  describe 'POST :create' do
    it "has the correct receivers" do
      post :create, { mailing: { receivers: [receiver.id] } }
      expect(Post.last.receivers).to eq [receiver]
    end
  end
end
```

Request (integration) spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe 'Mailings' do
  let!(:receiver) { create(:receiver) }
  describe 'POST /mailings' do
    it "has the correct receivers" do
      post '/mailings', { mailing: { receivers: [receiver.id] } }
      expect(Post.last.receivers).to eq [receiver]
    end
  end
end
```

Note however if you are using the rails collection helpers such as `collection_checkboxes` properly the param key should be `receiver_ids`.